Partition algorithm for minimal summation
Assume 2 sets of integer $A=\{a_1,...,a_n\},B=\{b_1,...,b_m\}$ I need to find a target $n$ partition of $B$, denote $B_1,...,B_n$ such that the maximum of $a_i+\sum_{b\in B_i}b$ is minimal.
I came up with a greedy algorithm that always adds the most significant element in B into the smallest sum with $a_i$, but it does not always produce the optimal case (counter-example: $A=\{4,5\}, B=\{3,4,5\}$ the algorithm will result in $4+5+3=12$ as a target, while $4+4+3=11$ should be the actual minimal)
Thus, I would like to ask if there is an algorithm to find the optimal case out of it with an acceptable time cost (maybe $n\leq 200, m\leq 500$).
Thanks!

Can $B_i$ be empty?

@enem yes $B_i$ can be empty

I think a deterministic algorithm might be impossible with these constraints, as the problem " Check whether a partion of integers into n sets, has the maximum subset sum <= W" is NP-hard. An approximation algorithm might be possible.

Is there any other constraint on the numbers like $\sum b_i \leq 10^3$ or something. Also by the term partition, is it set partitining ( where sets like ${b_1, b_3}, {b_2}$ are possible)  or is it array partitioning( where for all $i<j$, if $b_i \in B_x$ and $b_j\in B_y$ then $x\leq y$)

@enem thanks, then might be greedy method would be better

@enem normally $b_i<500$ and its set partition

Algorithms in the "Minimizing the maximum completion time (makespan)" section of https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identical-machines_scheduling might help

This is my answer:
This problem is strongly NP-hard: 3-partition problem is a special case with $a_i = 0$ for all $i$.
In practice, I would try using integer programming solvers. Example formulation:
$$
\begin{align}
& \min L \\
\text{s.t. } & a_i + \sum_j b_j x_{i,j} \leq L & \forall i \\
& \sum_i x_{i,j} = 1 & \forall j \\
& x_{i,j} \in \{0,1\} & \forall i, j
\end{align}
$$

Your objective should be minimization.
